# Disable animation with prefers-reduced-motion

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, accessibility

Today I wondered how someone would reset animations based on the `prefers-reduced-motion` property.
I found this [link](https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/11) which is very useful, but the discussion is ongoing there. The code which I tried works, but I'm wondering about the best-practice for this task.

My code:

```
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  *, ::before, ::after {
    animation-delay: -1s !important;
    animation-duration: 1s !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    background-attachment: initial !important;
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
    transition-duration: 0s !important;
  }
}
```

How could this be improved? Is this the best solution, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Well there isn't much you can do with it. It is `@media query`. It will trigger when specific condition is met.

Only thing that I think is redundant here is using `::before` and `::after` when you already have `*` because `*` will already target all elements.

And also use `:after` if you want to support older versions of IE (8 and before)

Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion) for more details

That's pretty much it

Comment: i dont think that the universal-selector will target pseudo-elements

Comment: ```The CSS universal selector (*) matches elements of any type.``` taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

Comment: yes elements, but not pseudo-elements.
you can see it here: https://jsbin.com/guxifoluqu/edit?html,css,output

just check the z-index from ::before